# When should one start looking for a postdoc?

Tags: job-search, postdocs

I'm doing my PhD in physics (experimental physics/materials science with a lot of programming) with more than one year to go. I'm not 100% sure if I want to stay in academia, but if so I would like to do multidisciplinary research, working mainly on the computational part. I changed research field multiple times and I'm not too scared to do that again.

When do you think I should start to look for a postdoc?

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by "more than one year to go"? How close is your thesis to be finished? Does your university have a rule saying you must stay there for a certain period of time?

Comment: @scaaahu yes my university is pretty strict regarding the  PhD deadline. Most students finish within 3 years and a few months.

Comment: The other question asks when you should start _applying_.  You should start _looking_ about three years ago.